# Update multiple records from a single column using values form another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `TableSource1` and I would like to take two fields named `tCIFTA` and `tCPlS` and copy that info. into another table named `TableDest` that has the same field names `tCIFTA` and `tCPlS` but only where the `UNIT_NO` are the same.

Table `TableDest` has alot of records that may contain the matching `UNIT_NO` multiple times and I would like to update all of them with the same info, so it would have to loop through the `TableDest` table looking for the matching `UNIT_NO` and if it finds a match it would update the two fields.

Something like this ?

```
UPDATE TableDest tCIFTA,tCPlS
SET
tCIFTA = (select tCIFTA from TableSource1 where UNIT_NO= TableDest.UNIT_NO)
tCPlS = (select tCPlS from TableSource1 where UNIT_NO= TableDest.UNIT_NO)

AND THEN LOOP THE TABLE: TableDest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
--(1) Check if you are getting correct results with this
Select Td.UNIT_NO, Ts.tCIFTA, Ts.tCPlS 
From TableDest Td join TableSource1 Ts 
        on Td.UNIT_NO = Ts.UNIT_NO

--(2) Run this if above query reuslts are correct to Update the table
Update Td set Td.tCIFTA = Ts.tCIFTA, Td.tCPlS = Ts.tCPlS
From TableDest Td join TableSource1 Ts 
        on Td.UNIT_NO = Ts.UNIT_NO
```

Please don't drop your table unless you are 100% sure about the results. Table drop syntax is:

```
DROP TABLE yourTableName
```